# Literature on Lyndon words and the Lie commutator

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, lie-groups, oa.operator-algebras, applied-mathematics

Since I lost my paper notes in a domestic conflagration in Japan some ten years ago, I've occasionally tried to recall one particular author who wrote in the 1900s about Lyndon words / strings, or such (perhaps I'm misusing the qualifier Lyndon, but see edit at bottom)--strings composed of two symbols, say $V$ and $U$--and their normal reordering via the commutator relation $[V,U] = VU -UV = 1$ such that all the $U$s are to the left of all the $V$s. This is, of course, connected to the normal re-ordering found in quantum mechanics (operator disentanglement), algebraic combinatorics, special function theory, and Graves-Pincherle-Lie theory. One of the most commonly depicted examples is, with $V = D = \tfrac{d}{dx}$ and $U = x$,

$$(xD)^n = ST2_n(:xD:),$$

where $:xD:^n = x^n D^n$ and $ST2_n(x)$ are the Stirling polynomials of the second kind / Touchard / Bell / exponential polynomials.

For example,

$[D,x] = Dx-xD = 1$, so $Dx = 1 + xD$

and

$(xD)^2 = xDxD = (xDx)D = (x (1+xD))D = xD + x^2D^2 = ST2_1(:xD:).$

Then, avoiding explicit iterative use of the commutator (but the following can be reduced to such because it defines differentiation),

$$(xD)^3 = xDxDxD = xD(xD)^2 = xD(xD +x^2D^2) $$

$$= x (D + xD^2 + 2 xD^2 + x^2D^2) = xD + 3x^2D^2 + x^3D^3 = :xD:^1 + 3:xD:^2 + :xD:^3$$

$$  = ST2_3(:xD:).$$

More generally,

$$(RL)^n = ST2_n(:RL:),$$

is true for any set of lowering and raising ops $L$ and $R$ acting on a space spanned by $\psi_n$ such that

$L \psi_n = n \psi_{n-1}$ and $R \psi_n = \psi_{n+1}.$

Another classic example, investigated by the likes of Stokes, Al-Salam, and Chatterjea, is

$$(RLR)^n = R^nL^nR^n = R^n :LR:^n = R^n Lah_n(:RL:) =n! R^n Lag^{(-1)}_n(-:RL:),$$

where $Lah_n(x)$ are the Lah polynomials and $Lag_n^{(-1)}(x)$ are the fundamental Laguerre polynomials of order -1. Conjugate this appropriately and you get a sequence used by Getzler in characterizing the Virasoro algebra.

Another: As Erdelyi, Gelfand, and Shilov knew, [reorder the binomial](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/107159/pochhammer-symbol-of-a-differential-and-hypergeometric-polynomials/107191#107191) $\binom{RL + \alpha + \beta}{\alpha}$ and you get the confluent hypergeometric functions.

This illustrates the ultimate importance of the re-ordering allowed by the commutator to the Sheffer polynomial calculus / finite operator calculus (see [this MO-Q](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/415441/how-are-sheffer-polynomials-related-to-lie-theory/415451#415451)) and related special functions ($(x+D)^n$, Hermite) and Weyl-Lie group theory, in which the Stirling polynomials of the first and second kinds and their refined versions the cycle index polynomials of the symmetric groups OEIS A036039 and the Faa di Bruno composition polynomials of A036040 play special roles.

All this ultimately issues from the commutator definition of derivation, so, at the very least from a historical viewpoint, it would be appropriate to acknowledge the work of the developers.

In "[Recent Developments in Combinatorial Aspects of Normal Ordering](https://ecajournal.haifa.ac.il/Volume2021/ECA2021_S2B2.pdf)", Matthias Schork (see also [this MO-Q](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/172899/differential-operator-simplification/172900#172900)) goes into some history and has a fairly extensive set of references listing several clans of collaborators that have published on this topic; however, he does leave out some important contributors such as Al-Salaam, Chatterjea, and Stokes (see. e.g., [this MO-A](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/107159/pochhammer-symbol-of-a-differential-and-hypergeometric-polynomials/107191#107191) and OEIS [A132440](https://oeis.org/A132440)) and Feinsilver.

My question:

**Other than the researchers listed in Schork's survey, who else has published since, say between 1950-2000, specifically on the notion of *re-ordering of strings of symbols explicitly using the commutator*?**

(Of course if you hadn't already been aware of the above elaboration, you probably have not come across the author and his papers that I've forgotten, but if you are interested in the combinatorics of string perhaps you have. In addition, if you've been particularly impressed by similar papers on the topic but not lying exactly within the scope of my criteria, I'd still be interested, e.g., see this [MO-Q](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/102281/a-mysterious-heisenberg-algebra-identity-from-sylvester-1867).)

Edit Mar 2, 2024:

From "[The origins of combinatorics on words](https://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/%7Eberstel/Articles/2007Origins.pdf)" by Jean Berstel, Dominique Perrin (2007),

> Lyndon words give rise to commutators through a process of iterated dichotomy, using the notion of standard factorization. For example, the Lyndon word aababb with standard factorization (a)(ababb) gives rise to the commutator [a,[[a, b],[[a, b], b]]].

Comment: The paper was at an elementary level, not related to mathematical logic nor computer science nor even graphics if I recall, and was probably published between 1950 and 2000. The only reason I take note of the phrase "Lyndon words" was from this paper. If I could be more concrete on the details, I could probably find it myself. At least, I know other users are interested in the content of Schork's paper

Comment: I'm not sure I've ever seen the Stirling polynomial formula connected to Lyndon words. But [arXiv:0704.3116](https://arxiv.org/abs/0704.3116) might be close to what you are looking for.

Comment: @darijgrinberg, yes, this clan is referenced by Schork. I'm well aware of them and conversely (was once asked for some refs by one). The paper I'm trying to find wasn't written by any of them. I probably first came across it circa 2001 before I took note of this clan. The author used the commutator to iteratively re-order an arbitrary string of $U$ and $V$s--maybe my first intro to such combinatorics so I would like to ref it in the future as homage (motivated also probably by some mild OCD irksomeness that I can't remember it). Keep a lookout please. // Perhaps I'm misusing 'Lyndon word'.

Comment: @darijgrinberg, that paper is always worth noting as well as the more comprehensive  book by Mansour and Schork" Commutation Relations, Normal Ordering, and Stirling Numbers".